# how to put Multiple Matrices Together into a Single Matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I need to put multiple matrices together into a single matrix, like so:

[image]

I have the values for the matrix, but I can't get it to appear like how it does in the image- instead, my values end up stacked on top of each other in an array. How can I go about getting my matrices to look like the image above?

My code:

```
import numpy as np

w_estimate = [0.656540, 7.192304, 2.749036]

F = [np.identity(3) * -w_estimate[1:4], -np.identity(3)], [np.identity(3)*0, np.identity(3)*0]
```

It's supposed to look like:

```
F =  [[np.identity(3) * -w_estimate[1:4],  -np.identity(3)]
      [np.identity(3) * 0,              np.identity(3) * 0]]
```

but instead it looks like:

```
[[np.identity(3) * -w_estimate[1:4]],
 [-np.identity(3)],
 [np.identity(3) * 0],
 [np.identity(3) * 0]]
```

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first correction to your code pertains to `-w_estimate[1:4]`.
Since *w_estimate* is a plain *pythonic* list, you can not apply
*minus* operator to it.

You can however apply *minus* operator to a *Numpy* array.

Another correction is to avoid *-0* in the result.
To get an array with diagonal elements filled from some other array,
and all other zeroes, you can use *np.diagonal_fill*, which fills
in-place diagonal elements of some (earlier) created array
(using *np.zeros*).

So to construct 2 "upper" blocks of your result, you can write:

```
a1 = np.zeros((3,3))
a2 = a1.copy()
np.fill_diagonal(a1, -np.array(w_estimate)[1:4])
np.fill_diagonal(a2, -1)
```

Note that `-np.array(w_estimate)[1:4]` returns last 2 elements of
w_estimate them, i.e. *[7.192304, 2.749036]*. Since the target array
is "3 by 3", the source sequence is repeated (in this case, for the
last diagonal element only).

If your intention is different, change `-np.array(w_estimate)[1:4]`
accordingly.

And to construct the whole intended array, run:

```
F = np.vstack((np.hstack((a1, a2)), np.zeros((3,6))))
```

The result is:

```
array([[-7.192304,  0.      ,  0.      , -1.      ,  0.      ,  0.      ],
       [ 0.      , -2.749036,  0.      ,  0.      , -1.      ,  0.      ],
       [ 0.      ,  0.      , -7.192304,  0.      ,  0.      , -1.      ],
       [ 0.      ,  0.      ,  0.      ,  0.      ,  0.      ,  0.      ],
       [ 0.      ,  0.      ,  0.      ,  0.      ,  0.      ,  0.      ],
       [ 0.      ,  0.      ,  0.      ,  0.      ,  0.      ,  0.      ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoud definitely take a look at [numpy.block](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.block.html#numpy.block) method.

```
>>> A = np.eye(2) * 2
>>> B = np.eye(3) * 3
>>> np.block([
...     [A,               np.zeros((2, 3))],
...     [np.ones((3, 2)), B               ]
... ])
array([[2., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 3., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 3., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 3.]])
```